# java applet to android workflow

Tags: android, applet

I have built an interactive taxonomic key and the output is a java applet. I want to covert it onto an app that can be used locally ie on phone for example with no connection to the internet (its important as people on project are working in remote locations). 
My question is can I edit the java applet in Android studio? Willing to learn just want to know what the best approach is. later would need to work on it being available on IOS devices too.
Thanks, Amanda

Answer (score 1):

Java applets and Android apps have nothing in common with each other, other than language.  The UI and input frameworks are totally different.  You could share some of the logic of the app if you put it into a jar file, but you won't be able to share anything else.  And Java doesn't run on iOS, so that's totally out.

Also, not sure why you tagged this javascript.  Java and javascript are totally different languages.  A Java applet has nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: thanks for replying apologies re tag. any ideas as to how to proceed? The keys are quite complicated... there are commercial approaches ie Lucid but they are really expensive… 
would I need to build the interactivity into the application in Android studio?

Comment: Im going to a cross platform that uses java, will post an answer to my question when ive worked it out